# Past continuous

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Please help me understand these sentences better:

> He called while I had been sleeping.

Is this correct? And, if it is what, is the difference between that and:

> He called me while I was sleeping?

Or:

> I was working when he called.

and

> I had been working when he called?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> He called while I had been sleeping.

Is wrong, I would rather say:

> He called while I was sleeping.

or

> He called while I was asleep.

Answer (score 0):

"I was working when he called" means that you were working at the moment he called and maybe you couldn't take the call at that moment.

"When he called I had been working" could mean two things:
either you had been working, for a period of time, until the moment he called, or you had just stopped working.